# Wofkflow when field changes refresh / submit data

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I have a field in an infopath form that counts items in another list. The field is working correctly but when the item count changes it can be seen when you open the list item but the change does not reflect in the list view until you go into the list item and save. Is there a way to set up a workflow that when a particular field changes to any value the workflow will refresh or submit the data so the changes can be seen in the list view?

Thanks in advance!

Dee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider creating a SharePoint Designer workflow to update the data and use an Information Policy Management retention rule to trigger the workflow daily.

[How to trigger a workflow on a timer basis: Information management policies](https://wardpeter.com/how-to-trigger-a-workflow-on-a-timer-basis-information-management-policies/)